# Add class to a div dynamically in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a div like this

```
<div ng-model="star"></div>
```

I want to add a class 'active' to this div in angular js.
I tried like this in my angular js controller

```
$scope.star.addClass('active');
```

But,I am getting error. I am new to angular js. please help me...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div ng-class="{ active: star == 'yes', 'in-active': star == 'no' }" ng-bind="star"></div>
```

You can have one or more classes assigned based on the expression (true or false).
If a class name has a hyphen, enclose in single quote.
This is a better approach and preferred than changing in controller.
Also, because this is a div, you have to do ng-bind, not ng-model.
ng-model works on fields like input.

UPDATE:

Since you insist on changing the class in code, here it is:

```
$("div[ng-bind='star']").addClass('active');
```

Comment: thnku for your answer. But i want to add class dynamically in controller. not in html.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access change class dynamically then you can put watch on your **star** variable in your controller like below :

```
$.watch('star',function(newVal, oldVal){ 
  // put your code to here based on new value and old value
  // you can add class to your div like :
  // angular.element("div[ng-bind='star']").addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a variable to control your class

```
<div ng-class="customClass"></div>
```

in controller

```
$scope.customClass = 'active custom-class1';
```

so, you can use if-else to change class name

```
if (something) {
    $scope.customClass = 'active custom-class1';
} else {
    $scope.customClass = 'deactive custom-class2';
}
```